# Mouse as interrupt

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB Psychtoolbox for understanding behaviour of human under critical condition.
I want to use mouse as an interrupt. To be more precise, a program is running and a mouse action is needed when an abnormality happens.Since presence of abnormality is not well defined so does the operator action. So I need to be always of action taken by human. How to keep track of human action with mouse?? 
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just mouse clicks or all mouse movement? For the former, you can just use the function `waitforbuttonpress`. Otherwise, if you need coordinates for example, you would use the `ginput` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the 'ButtonDownFcn' to your figure.
Have a look at [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/27/advanced-matlab-capture-mouse-movement/).

Comment: But i don't want to wait for user input via mouse. My whole program run behind and user input through mouse is not time specified.

Comment: yes, I understand. when you set the 'ButtonDownFcn' in a figure it will only execute when the user presses a button (not at a specified time). It is similar to a listener object in other programing languages.